# Should I use ActionBar pattern to make a choice between Camera and Gallery?

Tags: android, toolbar

I have baked the Camera and Gallery choices into the ActionBar at the top of the screen using a splashscreen as content.

I have even been told not to use the ActionBar at all.

This is my screen:

[image]

Should I use this, should I turn it into regular buttons or take it to the split action bar?

Comment: What do you think? How does the reasoning go? What are the arguments for not having an ActionBar? [Have you investigated it yourself?](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd follow one of these two ways:

#### **1. Drop the ActionBar**

If the main goal of this screen is to take a photo, users will most likely want to hold their devices in horizontal position. This will cause ActionBar to take up quite a lot of space, with very little of actual use to users.
The good example here is [native Camera app](http://youtu.be/umta7NfglAA?t=28s) (if I'm not mistaken since Jelly Bean). You can quickly jump to Gallery straight from Camera fragment just by swiping from right. Maybe this kind of behavior will do the job in your application. 
**Shortly:** don't use ActionBar, use swipe right-left gesture to switch between camera and gallery

#### **2. Transparent ActionBar**

If for some reason you'd still like to use ActionBar (eg. pictures will be mostly taken in portrait orientation), make it transparent to let user see the biggest possible image.
Don't use split action bar as it would take up even more space.
Some links that you mi find useful:

- [Pushing the ActionBar to the Next Level](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/)
- Fullscreen Android design: developer.android.com/design/patterns/fullscreen.html

**Shortly:** make ActionBar transparent and almost invisible to user

<sub>Hope it helped and I didn't do something wrong, as it is my first stackexchange answer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a single entry point for adding a card and judging by the way people usually use scanning apps, it should be directly into the camera mode.

While in the camera mode, you should have a button that takes you to the gallery and allows the user to choose an existing photo.

Without understanding how the content section looks with data, I'd say the camera button can stay on the nav bar - I expect that pressing it goes into camera mode anyway and doesn't return to the main app until a photo is snapped and selected.